# HTML - background-image margin from nowhere on moblie

Tags: html, css

Maybe someone knows, how to remove the **background-image margin** that appears only on mobile/tablet?

[image]

This is site to view like mobile: mobilephoneemulator.com

[**This**](http://geassnovels.ru/) is the problem in the site

Thanks.

Comment: could you share some code please? In jsfiddle or somewhere

Comment: jsfiddle can emulate mobile? I give 2 links - you can see code there

Comment: I am not sure what is it exactly you want. Are you talking about that faint thin white line just above those triangles in the screenshot?

Comment: Ohh you want it exactly like screenshot? You dont want those white lines in your site above nav items?

Comment: No, i dont want this lines :) http://i.stack.imgur.com/IoZWj.png  triangles, yes sorry for my bad eng.  Small gorizontal lines.

Comment: You have these properties:- .nav a:before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: #fff;
 content: '';
 -webkit-transition: top 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: top 0.3s;
 transition: top 0.3s;
}
.nav a:after {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 2px;
 height: 2px;
 background: #fff;
 content: '';
 -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
 transition: height 0.3s;
 border: 0;
}
If you remove these 2 css properties 'nav a before' and 'nav a after' those margins will disappear

Comment: nothing changed :(  https://s16.postimg.org/89sojidid/image.jpg

Comment: i repeat problem in PC browser with -webkit-background-size: 11px 11px; i think maybe it's somehow related to retina and image?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] rather than expecting us to trawl through the code of your entire site.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try following code I have debuged your website on mobile.

```
header {
background-color: #87CEEB;
min-height: 60px;
border: 1px solid #87ceeb!important;
}

.main{
background: url('https://s4.postimg.org/shvgf6cj1/cutheader.png');
}
```

I guess it is pixel density problem

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code to solved ur css issue, this will hide the white line

```
header{
   z-index: 1;
}
main{
   margin-top: -1px;
}
```

see screenshot [image: here]

Comment: to see what is the problem we need to dig into ur code and see whats wrong, what I gave u is css hacked to hide that white line

Comment: and why I received -1 when user says it solves the problem

Comment: Because it is not properly problem solution

Comment: @enhaster if u think this solves the problem you can mark it as answer

Comment: @user3041764 I know that, see my previous comment

Comment: what i gave here is one css hacked till the time he wont find real problem or he can continue with it

Comment: it's not working (bottom line is steal there), on RUstack, they say to draw svg :)   And one more thing, i add width to image +1px, and you can see line now on pc to (watch close). Just open this emulator (mobilephoneemulator.com) and insert my site, to see the problem

Comment: I have attached screenshot for reference

Answer (score -1):

I had 2 problems
1)margin-bottom: -1px (css in links)
2)bad retina browser resize. SVG image help.